# Akka HTTP REST API for producing to Kafka Performance

Tags: performance, scala, gatling, kafka-consumer-api, akka-http

I'm building an API with `Akka` that should produce to a `Kafka` bus. I have been load testing the application using `Gatling`. Noticed that when more than 1000 users are created in Gatling, the API starts to struggle. On average, about **170 requests per second are handled**, which seems like very little to me.

The API's main entry point is this:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem}

import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import play.api.libs.json.{JsObject, Json}

import scala.concurrent.{Future, ExecutionContext}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class PostMsg(msg:JsObject)
case object PostSuccess
case class PostFailure(msg:String)

class Msgapi(conf:Config) {
  implicit val um:Unmarshaller[HttpEntity, JsObject] = {
    Unmarshaller.byteStringUnmarshaller.mapWithCharset { (data, charset) =>
      Json.parse(data.toArray).asInstanceOf[JsObject]
    }
  }
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("MsgApi")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val router = system.actorOf(Props(new RouterActor(conf)))

  val route = {
    path("msg") {
      post {
        entity(as[JsObject]) {obj =>
          if(!obj.keys.contains("key1") || !obj.keys.contains("key2") || !obj.keys.contains("key3")){
            complete{
              HttpResponse(status=StatusCodes.BadRequest, entity="Invalid json provided. Required fields: key1, key2, key3 \n")
            }
          } else {
            onSuccess(router ? PostMsg(obj)){
              case PostSuccess => {
                complete{
                  Future{
                    HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, entity = "Post success")
                  }
                }
              }
              case PostFailure(msg) =>{
                complete{
                  Future{
                    HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity=msg)
                  }
                }
              }
              case _ => {
                complete{
                  Future{
                    HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity = "Unknown Server error occurred.")
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def run():Unit = {
    Http().bindAndHandle(route, interface = conf.getString("http.host"), port = conf.getInt("http.port"))
  }
}

object RunMsgapi {
  def main(Args: Array[String]):Unit = {
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
    val api = new Msgapi(conf)
    api.run()
  }
}
```

The router actor is as follows:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props, Actor}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext
import akka.routing.{Router, SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic, ActorRefRoutee}
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject

class RouterActor(conf:Config) extends Actor{

  val router = {
    val routees = Vector.tabulate(conf.getInt("kafka.producer-number"))(n => {
      val r = context.system.actorOf(Props(new KafkaProducerActor(conf, n )))
      ActorRefRoutee(r)
    })
    Router(SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic(), routees)
  }

  def receive = {
    case PostMsg(msg) => {
      router.route(PostMsg(msg), sender())
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, the kafka producer actor:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import java.util.Properties
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import kafka.message.NoCompressionCodec
import kafka.utils.Logging
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer._
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Await}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

class KafkaProducerActor(conf:Config, id:Int) extends Actor with Logging {
  var topic: String = conf.getString("kafka.topic")
  val codec = NoCompressionCodec.codec

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", conf.getString("kafka.bootstrap-servers"))
  props.put("acks", conf.getString("kafka.acks"))
  props.put("retries", conf.getString("kafka.retries"))
  props.put("batch.size", conf.getString("kafka.batch-size"))
  props.put("linger.ms", conf.getString("kafka.linger-ms"))
  props.put("buffer.memory", conf.getString("kafka.buffer-memory"))
  props.put("key.serializer", conf.getString("kafka.key-serializer"))
  props.put("value.serializer", conf.getString("kafka.value-serializer"))

  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

  def receive = {
    case PostMsg(msg) => {
      // push the msg to Kafka
      try{
        val res = Future{
          producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, msg.toString()))
        }
        val result = Await.result(res, 1 second).get()
        sender ! PostSuccess
      } catch{
        case e: Exception => {
          println(e.printStackTrace())
          sender ! PostFailure("Kafka push error")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea being that in application.conf I can easily specify how many producers there should be, allowing better horizontal scaling.

Now, however, it seems that the api or router is actually the bottleneck. As a test, I disabled the Kafka producing code, and replaced it with a simple: `sender ! PostSuccess`. With 3000 users in Gatling, I still had 6% of requests failing due to timeouts, which seems like a very long time to me.

The Gatling test I am executing is the following:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._ // 2
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class BasicSimulation extends Simulation { // 3
val httpConf = http // 4
    .baseURL("http://localhost:8080") // 5
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") // 6
    .doNotTrackHeader("1")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")

  val scn = scenario("MsgLoadTest")
    .repeat(100)(
      pace(2 seconds)
      .exec(http("request_1")
      .post("/msg").body(StringBody("""{ "key1":"something", "key2": "somethingElse", "key3":2222}""")).asJSON)
    )

  setUp( // 11
    scn.inject(rampUsers(3000) over (5 seconds)) // 12
  ).protocols(httpConf) // 13
}
```

**update**

Following some pointers from cmbaxter, I tried some things (see discussion in comments), and profiled the application using visualvm during the gatling load test. I don't quite know how to interpret these results though. It seems that a lot of time is spent in the ThreadPoolExecutor, but this might be ok?
Two screenshots from the profiling are below:
[image: CPU profile]

[image: Thread snapshot]

Comment: This line of code, `val result = Await.result(res, 1 second).get()` is blocking.  Blocking code will not perform well within an akka system.  You should refactor that part to not block.

Comment: @cmbaxter Good point, I'll change that. For the moment I commented that part out though, so in the receive of KafkaProducerActor the only code is this: `case PostMsg(msg) => sender ! PostSuccess`. Yet still approx 6% of the requests are failing. Gatling indicates that the connections are timing out...

Comment: Why are you using an explicit Router actor instead of just applying a router to the kafka producer actor yourself?  Something like:  `val producerPool = system.actorOf(SmallestMailboxPool(size).props(Props(new KafkaProducerActor(conf))), "producerRouter)`.

Comment: @cmbaxter Would using that construction significantly speed up the API? I can make the change of course. I have no real reason to have a separate router actor.

Comment: An actual `Router` (vs an actor acting as a router) has significantly optimized mailbox handling.  That actor you are using is a bottleneck as there is only one of them and it has to deal with it's mailbox and the throughput setting for the actor system.  An actual `Router` as I suggested in my previous comment won't have this problem.  It might help.

Comment: Read the "How routing is designed within Akka" from this link for more info on that: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/routing.html

Comment: @cmbaxter Ok, I tried that. Makes sense now you mention it. I now replaced the Actor creation in MsgApi with `val producerPool = system.actorOf(SmallestMailboxPool(5).props(Props(new KafkaProducerActor(conf, 1))), "producerRouter")
`. Then I replaced the `router ? PostMsg(obj)` with `producerPool ? PostMsg(obj)`. Re-ran gatling, but sadly no change. Still 6% of the requests are timing out. Is the ask pattern the best way to go here? Could it impact performance?

Comment: My only suggestion to you now is to profile it and see where the hotspot is.

Comment: Since you are creating new KafkaProducerActor for every http request, you are KafkaProducer everytime, are you sure you need that much producers? Create a single actor instance and just send messages to it, this way you will always send 1 connection per actor per time, so one KafkaProducer should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude the Kafka producer, I removed the logic from the Actor. I was still getting performance issues. So, as a final test, I reworked the API to simply give a direct answer when a POST came in:

```
val route = {
    path("msg") {
      post {
        entity(as[String]) { obj =>
          complete(
            HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, entity = "OK")
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and I implemented the same route in Spray, to compare performance. The results were clear. Akka HTTP (at least in this current test setup) does not come close to Spray's performance. Perhaps there is some tweaking that can be done for Akka HTTP? I have attached two screenshots of response time graphs for 3000 concurrent users in Gatling, making a post request.

Akka HTTP
[image]

Spray
[image]

Comment: You are correct in that Akka http does not yet match Spray in terms of performance. The guys at Typesafe were initially focused on locking down the API before focusing on performance. I think now they are starting to tune things so soon the performance will start to catch up to that of Spray.

Comment: @cmbaxter Yeah I read that performance had not been their focus. I didn't expect the difference to be this huge though... For now I'll use Spray, hopefully I can move to Akka HTTP in the future once performance is better. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: is it still relevant ? I mean spray vs akka http ?

Answer (score 0):

I would eliminate the `KafkaProducerActor` and router completely and call a Scala wrapped version of `producer.send` directly. Why create a possible bottleneck if not necessary? I could very well imagine the global execution context or the actor system becoming a bottleneck in your current setup.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
class KafkaScalaProducer(val producer : KafkaProducer[String, String](props)) {
    def send(topic: String, msg : String) : Future[RecordMetadata] = {
        val promise = Promise[RecordMetadata]()
        try {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, msg), new Callback {
                override def onCompletion(md : RecordMetadata, e : java.lang.Exception) {
                    if (md == null) promise.success(md)
                    else promise.failure(e)
                }
            })
        } catch {
            case e : BufferExhaustedException => promise.failure(e)
            case e : KafkaException => promise.failure(e)
        }
        promise.future
    }

    def close = producer.close
}
```

*(note: I have not actually tried this code. It should be interpreted as pseudo-code)*

I would then simply `transform` the result of the future to a `HttpResponse`.

After that it's a question of tweaking configuration. Your bottleneck is now either the Kafka Producer or Akka Http.